# Java - Comparing 2 floats (or doubles)

Tags: java, floating-point, double, comparator

I have an ArrayList that I need to sort by width, which is stored as a float (.getWidth() returns a float)

```
arrayPlaceholder.sort((m1,m2) -> font.getWidth(m2.getDisplayName()) - font.getWidth(m1.getDisplayName()));
```

I have looked around the docs and at the error i'm getting, and it's clear that the function .compare(), returns only an int.

Is there any way to compare 2 floats (or doubles, as I **can** convert floats into doubles); in my usage? I've looked at other posts but I don't want to hardcode this process.

Comment: The function you pass to `sort` expects int return because it determines the ordering. You do not need to return a float there, your list will still contain the original values.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the [documentation of the interface `Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html).

Comment: @Turing85 I did look at the documentation, but all I could get from there is that compare() returns an int, and nothing else.

Comment: "*Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
(m1,m2) -> 
  Float.valueOf( // <- need object wrapper here (only)
    font.getWidth(m1.getDisplayName()))
  .compareTo(
    font.getWidth(m2.getDisplayName())
  )
```

[`Float#compareTo(java.lang.Float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html#compareTo(java.lang.Float))

Also possible:

```
(m1,m2) -> 
  Float.compare( //
    font.getWidth(m1.getDisplayName()),
    font.getWidth(m2.getDisplayName())
  )
```

For **descending order**: Switch `m1` with `m2` (*xOr* in parameters (m2, m1) *xOR* in (lambda) body).

Comment: "Cannot invoke compareTo(float) on the primitive type float"

Comment: ya, sorry, i don't have the concrete classes/apis/data at hand: to fix "cannot invoke", it should be sufficient, to wrap the 1st `float` into `Float`: with `Float.valueOf(float f)` or `new Float(float f)`

Comment: Or, forget about wrapper objects, and use [Float.compare](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html#compare(float,float))(font.getWidth(m1.getDisplayName()), font.getWidth(m2.getDisplayName())).

Comment: well it worked both ways, thanks (also had to switch m1 with m2, as they seem to be sorted the other way around)